# RxJava retry N times

Tags: rx-java

RxJava 2

I am trying to make very simple retry in rxJava, that would retry 3 times and then result in original error. Here is what I have now:

```
public void retry3() {
    Observable<Object> retry = Observable
         .error(new IllegalStateException())
         .retryWhen(errors -> errors
             .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> {
                  System.out.println("Retry: " + i);
                  return i;
             }));

    System.out.println("start");
    retry.blockingFirst();
    System.out.println("stop");
}
```

But executing above results in:

```
start
Retry: 1
Retry: 2
Retry: 3
```

And then execution seems to block forever. So two questions:

- How to make this work?
- Why it does not work like it is and how should I have debugged it?

Comment: on a side note, this case of very simple retry is supported out-of-the-box: `.retry(3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the final result to be the first error, so you need to keep track of it somehow. A working solution would be:

```java
public void retry3() {
    // this is just some preparation so we can see the result and understand it better.
    // Basically, this is an Observable that will:
    // - fail with different exceptions
    // - show us what those are
    final Random random = new Random();
    final Observable<Object> errorReturningObservable = Observable
            .just(0)
            .flatMap(i -> Observable.error(new Exception("Exception " + random.nextInt())))
            .doOnError(error -> System.out.println("Emitted " + error.getMessage()));

    // Here is the actual retry logic:
    // - If there's an error, resume by doing the retry
    // - If at the end of the retries, there's still an error, return the original one
    final Observable<Object> retryingObservable = errorReturningObservable
            .onErrorResumeNext(error -> errorReturningObservable
                    .retry(2)
                    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.error(error))
    );

    System.out.println("start");
    retryingObservable
            .subscribe(
                    result -> System.out.println("Won't get here!"),
                    error -> System.out.println("The final error is: " + error.getMessage())
            );
    System.out.println("stop");
}
```

If you run this, you should see something like:

```
start
Emitted Exception 2138850329 << first emitted error
Emitted Exception 1806115610
Emitted Exception -40768559
Emitted Exception 871227422
The final error is: Exception 2138850329 << matches the one returned at the end
stop
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`blockingFirst()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingFirst()) docs:

> Returns the first item emitted by this Observable, or throws
>   NoSuchElementException if it emits no items.

in your case, the Observable works just fine, but it throws the `NoSuchElementException` as eventually no item emitted. you'r retrying 3 times and then the `Observable` ends - sends `onComplete()`.

> How to make this work?

you can use `blockingSubscribe()`, and then your case will work as expected.

> Why it does not work like it is and how should I have debugged it?

in this case you should observer the exception to know that something wrong happen, you can use `doOnXXX()` operators to add printing at various notifications to observe what is wrong and not working as expected.

Comment: You are correct. The exception is thrown. I am not sure how I managed to observe the behaviour of it just blocking for ever. Now that I retried, it indeed throws 'NoSuchElementException' as would be exptected. How ever, as I stated I want to return the original exception instead.